# Euler Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What's the best method to convert this equation $$(x-3)^2y''+5(3-x)y'+9y=0$$ into an Euler Differential Equation? $$$$

I've tried already by using $y=x^m$ but I get $$x^m[m^2(x^{-2}-6x^{-1}+1)+m(-9x^{-2}+21x^{-6}-6)+9]$$

$$$$Also tried the substitution $x=e^t$ from where I get: $$\ddot y(1-6x^{-1}+9x^{-2})+\dot y(-6+21x^{-1}-9x^{-2})+9y =0$$

which clearly have not simplified the problem to an Euler DE. $$$$ Any suggestion or idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try $y=(x-3)^m \times z(x)$ instead.

Comment: Funny, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\tilde{x} = x -3$, then we have

$$ \tilde{x}^2 y''- 5 \tilde{x} y' + 9y = 0 $$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was so easy that I didn't expect it.